# How inject Logger in custom service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ImportExportService.

In StartUp class in method ConfigureServices I use it as

```
services.AddImportExportService(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

**Extential method AddImportExportService:**

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddImportExportService(this IServiceCollection services, 
            string connString,
            ILogger<ImportExportService> logger
            )
        {
            services.AddTransient<IImportExportService, ImportExportService>(provider => new ImportExportService(connString));
            return services;
        }
    }
```

ExportImportService uses logging. 
I tried to inject Logging in service as param in constructor like `ILoger<ImportExportService> logger`, but constructor includes only one param and extension method AddImportExportService get error.

How inject Logging in ExportImportService? Thank you

Comment: You show the extension using only the one parameter. How and where is the logger used?

Comment: Why does `AddImportExportService` accept an `ILogger<ImportExportService>`? Should this not be resolved from the container? I'd probably take a look at the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) too.

Comment: @Nkosi I have methods in Service and in try-catch if error I need record error or success in logs like `logger.LogInformation(e.Message);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
services.AddTransient<IImportExportService, ImportExportService>(provider => new ImportExportService(connString));
```

should be

```
services
    .AddTransient<IImportExportService, ImportExportService>(
        provider => new ImportExportService(connString, provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<ImportExportService>>()));
```

assuming the constructor of `ImportExportService` has two arguments. Then the extension needs only two arguments:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddImportExportService(
    this IServiceCollection services, 
    string connString)
```

Comment: thank you. i dint know that i can call required service this way.